# Why is gnome-software service running in the background?

Tags: 16.04, gnome-software

It doesn't make much sense to me when there's a service running idle as a package installer (namely `gnome-software --gapplication-service`)

Answer (score 3):

It does for me: you need a service to catch possible available updates.

Besides that: it is just the service part (`gnome-software-service`) of gnome-software that is running.

Comment: Does it only check for Snap updates? Cause I don't think it's ever notified me of updates, but I also disabled Snaps.

Answer (score 2):

If you update manually then it can be removed from autostart. See:
[Disable gnome-software from loading at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959353/disable-gnome-software-from-loading-at-startup)

It sparked my interest when I inspected my dnsmasq log and found all of the package repository servers being resolved once a day. This would occur immediately after an internet connection was established.

I thought I had put an end to all auto-update features but I missed this one. The Ubuntu Documentation for Automatic Connections applies only to 14.04 LTS too which didn't help me (running 16.04).