# Disable gnome-software from loading at startup

Tags: autostart, startup-applications, gnome-software

Gnome-software, which is one of the top memory consumers, is being loaded at startup and thus decreasing boot time.
[image]

I rarely use gnome-software, and on most boot-ups it is useless. However there is not an entry at start-up apps, not even after [showing hidden startup apps](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ShowHiddenStartupApplications). Also, I haven't found any gnome-software-related process from systemd-analyze to disable it with systemctl.

Answer (score 29):

Go to `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-software-service.desktop` and remove the line

```
NoDisplay=true
```

or change `true` to `false`. Then *GNOME Software* should appear in your **Startup Applications** list. You can disable it from there.

If *GNOME Software* still doesn't appear in *Startup Applications* list following the suggestion above, follow the steps below.

1. Copy `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-software-service.desktop` to the `~/.config/autostart/` directory.
2. Open the copied `.desktop` file with a text editor and remove the line

   ```
   NoDisplay=true
   ```

   or change `true` to `false`.
3. Now *GNOME Software* should appear in your *Startup Applications* list. Disable it. Alternatively, you may append an

   ```
   X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
   ```

   line to the copied `.desktop` file.

Answer (score 11):

From https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/92941/how-to-stop-fedora-24-gnome-software-auto-updating/, try these two options:

1. Disable it in gsettings

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.software download-updates false
   ```
2. If that fails .. mask (disable) the backend service, PackageKit, the service used by Gnome Software.

   ```
   sudo systemctl mask packagekit.service
   ```

Comment: Following your instructions, I noticed that upon bootup, gnome software is seen loaded at system-monitor, and after some seconds it exits. This solves the ram-consume-problem but slowing-bootup persists.

Comment: Debugging boot is different. Did you mask  packagekit ? Debugging boot is almost another question, but did you run blame ? https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/systemd-blame.html

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 22.04, I found none of the suggestions above helpful. While I was able to see Gnome Software in Startup Applications, disabling it here did not help. Removing both the global desktop file and the local one did not stop it from starting.

It is started because it is a service defined here:

```
/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.gnome.Software.service
```

In that directory, do:

```
sudo mv org.gnome.Software.service org.gnome.Software.service_disabled
```

I don't know what side effects this has yet.